# Django ORM Group By Date Range

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django Model where users can be assigned a status for a specific period, e.g. 'Absent' from 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-20:

```py
class Status(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='statuses')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=status_choices)
    valid_from = models.DateField()
    valid_to = models.DateField()
```

What I'm trying to calculate: the status for each user, for each week:

```
Mr. A    Week 1    Absent
Mr. A    Week 2    Present
Mr. A    Week 3    Present
Mr. B    Week 1    Absent
Mr. B    Week 2    Absent
Mr. B    Week 3    Present
```

The only thing I can come up with, is to create a for loop and iterate over all the dates that I want to include:

```py
for date in dates:
   Status.objects.filter(valid_from__lte=date, valid_to__gt=date).values('user__username', 'status')[:1]
```

But as one can imagine, it creates way too many queries.. anyone that knows a way to to this in a single ORM query?

Comment: Is a week enclosed within `valid_from` and `valid_to`, i.e. a `Status` can be only in one week? Or it can stretch over more than one `Status`?

Comment: A `Status` can be `valid_from`and `valid_to` on any date. There can even be multiple statuses in one week. That's why I always take the first occuring status in that week.